# No color in Vim while using Google Cloud Shell

Tags: shell

I am using the Google Cloud Shell and wanted to [install a theme](https://github.com/mhartington/oceanic-next#installation) for Vim. Adding the following to my `.vimrc` (using `vim-plug` as a plugin manager):

```
Plug 'mhartington/oceanic-next'

syntax enable

if (has("termguicolors"))
 set termguicolors
endif

colorscheme OceanicNext
```

But after doing so, everything appears in black and white:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Has someone an Idea why that happens and how to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by « install a theme for vim » (specific steps?) and what « appears in black and white » means?

Comment: What is CloudShell? Is that a terminal? Did you play around with setting the `t_Co` option value or the `'terminal'` option value?

Comment: It also would be interesting to know the value of `$TERM` in the shell.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It is the cloud shell available on Google Cloud Platform, I think.

Comment: so is this a terminal? You need to configure it correctly. I guess, Vim cannot detect its features and therefore disables all sophisticated terminal features. As I said, play around with `t_Co` and the `'terminal'` option value (try to use a builtin terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) mentioned the right answer in [his comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18219/no-color-in-vim-while-using-google-cloud-shell?noredirect=1#comment31411_18219). It was the `t_Co` option I needed to set. And remove the `termguicolors` option.

My .vimrc looks now like this:

```
" Loading Plugin
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug ('mhartington/oceanic-next')
call plug#end()

" Theme
syntax enable
set t_Co=256
colorscheme OceanicNext
```

The confusion came cause I followed the [installation instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/mhartington/oceanic-next#installation) which say, that I should use `set termguicolors` with vim 8. And I have vim 8 installed but needed to use the instructions for vim 7.